# Insert data in sqlite table dynamically not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I want to insert the data in a SQLite table login when a button is clicked, the problem is that when I click on the register button data is getting stored in variable but not in database table, and When I try to statically pass the value the data will be insert but When i trying to dynamically store data then not work.

Here is my code. Please go through it and help to solve this issue.

```
NSString *path; 

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask ,YES);

path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

dbName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mnc.sqlite"]];

NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbName]== NO)
{
  const char *dbPath = [dbName UTF8String];

  if (sqlite3_open(dbPath,&connectionDB)==SQLITE_OK) 
  {
    char *errMsg;
    const char *sql_stmt = " create table if not exists login(user_name text ,password text)";

    if (sqlite3_exec(connectionDB,sql_stmt,NULL,NULL,&errMsg))
    {
      printf("\n fail to create table ");
    }

    sqlite3_close(connectionDB);
  }
  else 
  {
    NSLog(@"fail to open create database");
  }
}

[fileMgr release];

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(connectionDB, query ,-1, &statment,NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
  sqlite3_bind_text(statment,1,"cc", -1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statment,2,"sa",-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
  NSLog(@"aadd");
}

if (sqlite3_step(statment)== SQLITE_DONE)
{
  NSLog(@"This should be real error checking!");
  sqlite3_finalize(statment);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite complex to work with sqlite, thats why I use [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) this will simplify the work.

> This is an Objective-c wrapper around SQLite

Hope this helps.